# BigQuery / Count the number of rows until a specific row is reached 2

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in BigQuery.

I want to count the number of 'pending' events before their 'approved' event per ID.

Attention. If the ID does not have 'approved', then that group of events should not be counted (see the last two rows).

How would I get the value for every individual ID?

Table events

```
id  event
1   pending
1   pending
1   pending
1   approved
2   pending
1   pending
1   pending
1   approved
2   approved
1   pending 
1   pending
```

In this example the right result is

```
id  count_events
1   3
1   2
2   1
```

Comment: "*[If an ORDER BY clause is not present, the order of the results of a query is not defined.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause)*". SQL rows have no inherent order. You'd need a timestamp or something to define the order of the results.

Comment: OHH YES. I have a timestamp. Sorry I forgot say.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Schwern, if you don't have a column giving you an idea of the order of the events, you cannot get the result you expect.

That being said, here is a solution if you have a `event_date` or `event_timestamp` column:

```
WITH temp AS(
  SELECT
    id,
    event,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_date) AS rownum
  FROM
    sample )
SELECT
  id,
  event,
  rownum-COALESCE(LAG(rownum) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rownum), 0)-1 AS count_events
FROM
  temp
WHERE
  event = 'approved'
```

With the data you provided, it returns the desired output:

[image]

The logic behind the query is to say that the count of 'pending's before an 'approved' is the position of the 'approved' (it's row number) minus the position of the previous 'approved' minus 1.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't enough info for me to write an exact query but you could use GROUP BY and COUNT

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, event, COUNT(event)
FROM 'table'
GROUP BY id, event)
WHERE event <> 'approved'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).